# Customer specific database records

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

What we have right now:
1. SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition
2. 100 tables
3. ~1000-2000 pieces of programmability (Stored procs, functions, etc)

5 of our tables contain global information that is applicable to all customers. The rest of  the tables contain information specific to a customer.

So, we have to add Customer_Id to each of those tables. One customer can have >100000 records in one table.
We want to achieve the following:
1. Separate data by customer, so they can login to their application by navigating to: `http://Customer.ourApp.com`
2. Speed things up.

The most straightforward solution would be to use separate databases, but I don't like the idea because of number of implications:
1. need to mirror global data
2. Harder to mainting when developing and releasing
3. Harder to set-up new customers.

What are possible approaches to look into? any interesting reads? any general advice?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do? For #1, you go write a website (presumably in ASP.NET). For #2, you optimize #1. Can you be more specific about what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Why would you have to add an additional database?  It seems like you could do all of this by setting up the database you have with the necessary relations

Comment: @msm8bball, we want to separate data because of performance penalty.

Comment: So you're moving from a design that was for a single customer, and now it needs to support multiple customers? That's why you need to add Customer_Id to each of the non-global tables? How many customers? Or is it already set up this way for multiple customers, but you are not satisfied with performance?

Comment: @jugg1es, we do have relations, we just want to keep data from mixing up. something similar is done by oracle when you can apply policy to all tables, or it's also called multi-tenant architecture

Comment: @hatchet, yes, you're correct. we are planning to have up to 100 customers. The problem is that each customer holds hierarchical data, which is pretty complex for joins and manipulation

Comment: It honestly sounds like you need to revisit your database architecture all together.  If you originally designed the database for a single customer, you would be better served to totally redesign it to support multiple customers.

Comment: Before you go moving data into new databases, why don't you optimize your existing tables? Or create two test systems and then compare the performance difference and use the information from that to determine how to proceed?

Comment: I would definitively break the big database in smaller ones. Mirroring global data could be achieved with a dedicated database. 
Maintenance is a problem that could be easily solved with the appropriate tools (in house built or acquired). Setup of a new customer could be resolved with an 'empty' database ready to import when need arises (and again, an appropriate script could solve the problem once and forever). However, the greater gain, is the simplification of functionality. You'll no longer need a CustomerID field, which, I imagine, is a bit all over the place in your SP.

Comment: Is the "global data" used independently or does it particpate in queries with the customer data?  Would it be practical to have everyone share a global data database and have a separate per-customer database?  Having an application access multiple databases isn't a problem.  Performing `JOIN`s and the like between databases raises some issues.